# Adding subject of LYNC message

Tags: excel, vba, lync

Every single code I have found re sending LYNC message is without subject of the message.
What I need is to entitle the message that I send to a specific user.
Below a typical code snippet one can find on sending messages with no info on message subject.

Can someone advise how to add subject line, please?
It is for sure possible as can be manually obtained by clicking 'Change Conversation Subject' in the message window.
As I need to work with excel file and am clueless on real coding I need VBA lines.

Thanks in avdance.

```
Sub przeskok()
    Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
    Dim ToUser As String
    Dim message As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ToUser = "Konrad.P@XXX.com"
    message = "***w pliku KPI brak danych o ewentualnych spóznionych zamówieniach***"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(ToUser)
    'Send message to window
    msgr.SendText (message)
    'msgr.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```